# CSS z-index not working

Tags: jquery, css

I created a user hovercard but i have z-index problem.

If you can check this demo then you can see there are tree avatar = **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sw4ev8b4/10/)**

So hover over any image then hovercar will open but Hovercard is far below the picture below. How can i fix it anyone can help me here ?

```
<div class="the-container">
    <div class="summary-mask"></div>
    <div class="summary" data-id="50"> <a href="http://kraigo.tumblr.com/" class="profile-ava"></a>
        <div class="user-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.summary-mask {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.loaded .summary-mask {
    z-index: -1;
}
.profile-ava {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(http://gravatar.com/avatar/3913c4e14034c0a7f28db2c632290c21?s=80);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    display: block;
}
.summary a:hover:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.p-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -140px;
    width: 280px;
    max-height: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Just want to point you to [some interesting resources](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) on [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/sw4ev8b4/14/

Remove all the fancy z-index styling you have in there and just add a positive z-index `z-index:999;` to your tooltip:

```
.summary {
    margin: -50px auto 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.summary-mask {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.p-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -140px;
    width: 280px;
    max-height: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index:999;
}
```